# Using cloud-init to install a specific package version

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-init

In the `cloud-init` documentation, it says it is possible to install packages with something like

```
packages:
 - nginx
 - php
```

However, I have not found a way to specify a specific version number for a package, e.g. nginx v1.6.0, or PHP 5.5.12

Is this possible? I would like to use the cloud-init as part of the AWS EC2 user data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Install arbitrary packages](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html#install-arbitrary-packages) in *Cloud config examples*:

> [P]ackages may be supplied as a single package name or as a list with
>   the format [package, version] wherein the specifc [sic] package
>   version will be installed.